# Is linear regression appropriate for this analysis ? what additional operations to do?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, econometrics, data-transformation, descriptive-statistics, data-mining

I haven't done statistics / econometrics for a long time. I haven't done a lot by the way. But I would like advice on some methods and tests to be performed on two excel files that I have.

Each excel file contains thousands of lines. One line is for "a paper file" (in the real life) and there are dozens of columns.

The first excel file contains data concerning closed cases (closed in the period 2015-2020) and the second excel file contains data concerning non-closed cases.
A lot of columns are qualitative variables: nature of the file (fiscal, HR, ...), the department that manages it, the department that created the file, the name of the creator, ... and other variables such as the number of project managers on the file, the number of type A employees involved in the file, the number of type B employees, the numbers of pages in the file... and also variables such as the case start date, the case closing date (in the event that the files are closed).(and sometimes intermediate event dates).

I would like to do an analysis to "make the data talk" about the processing time and what influences it. To do this I work on the two files separately.

For the first, I calculate the processing time: end case date - begining case date -> and I have the processing time expressed in days.(for the closed files-cases)
From this, I would like to try to explain what are the (main) factors that influence the average processing time of a case.
My question: should I use "linear regression model"? And how to "mix" qualitative and quantitative variables (if possible).

I would like to repeat the same thing afterwards but by separating the files by nature (fiscal, HR, ...). The goal would be to have the main elements that determine the processing time of a specific type of file.

What other operations / questions could I also carry out to reveal interesting informations in relation to the processing time of cases?

the second excel file contains unfinished folders/files/cases. There are also old files lying around. What tests / questions can I do to compare with the results of the first excel file?

Hoping that my English is an understandable minimum :)

thanks in advance ! ;)

Gilgamesh

Comment: This sounds like a survival-analysis situation. You presumably have some cases that are not yet closed; you should not remove them from the inference (since that biases your estimates), but you need to account for the fact that the 'survival' times are censored (which is what survival analysis does). You can fit regression-like models. If you want a model for *average* processing time in terms of a set of predictors you'd need a parametric survival model (there are a number of potentially suitable ones to choose from).

Comment: I would start by plotting data. You might find, for example, that closed cases are not simply distributed. For example, there could be easy cases that are closed quickly, and hard cases that take longer to close. Also, how many people were or are assigned to a particular case may be variable in time; some cases might initially have been assigned to one person and then have expanded to multiple people. I am curious, what are type A and B employees? Sounds a bit like [Brave New World](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/5129.Brave_New_World), i.e., dystopian.

Comment: type A and B employees (and C... ) are for the teams. If the case is "easy", in general there is 1 or 2 employees from team A. Bigger the case, more employees from more team are concerned. And number of people assigned is fixed for all the processing of the case